# Airflow 2: Job Not Found when transferring data from BigQuery into Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to migrate from Cloud Composer 1 into Cloud Composer 2 (from Airflow 1.10.15 into Airflow 2.2.5) and when attempting to load data from BigQuery into GCS using the `BigQueryToGCSOperator`

```
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.bigquery_to_gcs import BigQueryToGCSOperator 

# ...

BigQueryToGCSOperator(
    task_id='my-task',
    source_project_dataset_table='my-project-name.dataset-name.table-name',
    destination_cloud_storage_uris=f'gs://my-bucket/another-path/*.jsonl',
    export_format='NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
    compression=None,
    location='europe-west2'
)
```

that results into the following error:

```
[2022-06-07, 11:17:01 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1776} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/bigquery_to_gcs.py", line 141, in execute
    job = hook.get_job(job_id=job_id).to_api_repr()
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/common/hooks/base_google.py", line 439, in inner_wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/bigquery.py", line 1492, in get_job
    job = client.get_job(job_id=job_id, project=project_id, location=location)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 2066, in get_job
    resource = self._call_api(
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 782, in _call_api
    return call()
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 283, in retry_wrapped_func
    return retry_target(
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 190, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/_http/__init__.py", line 494, in api_request
    raise exceptions.from_http_response(response)

google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 GET https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/my-project-name/jobs/airflow_1654592634552749_1896245556bd824c71f31c79d28cdfbe?projection=full&prettyPrint=false: Not found: Job my-project-name:airflow_1654592634552749_1896245556bd824c71f31c79d28cdfbe
```

Any clue what may be the issue here and why it does not work on Airflow 2.2.5 (even though the equivalent `BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator` works for Cloud Composer v1 in Airflow 1.10.15).

Comment: What region is the table in BigQuery? Is it multi-region (`EU`)? or is it `europe-west2`?

Comment: @DanielT It's `europe-west2`. I have already tried with `location='EU'` as well, without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this seems to be a bug introduced in `apache-airflow-providers-google` version `v7.0.0`.

Also note that the file transfer from BQ into GCS will actually be successful (even though the task will fail).

---

As a workaround you can either revert back to a working version (if this is possible) e.g. to `6.8.0`, or make use of the BQ API and get rid of `BigQueryToGCSOperator`.

For example,

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator


def load_bq_to_gcs():
    client = bigquery.Client()
    job_config = bigquery.job.ExtractJobConfig()
    job_config.destination_format = bigquery.DestinationFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON

    destination_uri = f"{<gcs-bucket-destination>}*.jsonl"

    dataset_ref = bigquery.DatasetReference(bq_project_name, bq_dataset_name)
    table_ref = dataset_ref.table(bq_table_name)

    extract_job = client.extract_table(
        table_ref,
        destination_uri,
        job_config=job_config,
        location='europe-west2',
    )
    extract_job.result()
```

and then create an instance of `PythonOperator`:

```
PythonOperator(
    task_id='test_task',
    python_callable=load_bq_to_gcs,
)
```

Comment: thanks - do you know if there is a github issue we can track? - we are having same trouble here

Comment: oh found it :) https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/24277